# Check whether a selected option is exists in dynamically created arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got some code that looks like this.  The values of `select#member_id` get added dynamically by PHP. I'm trying to determine whether the user selects a `res` or `com` option from the list, which will determine whether I dynamically add in a second dropdown.  With the code as is, I consistently get -1 alerted by the script.  The `console.log` call prints out: `[1, 3] [2]`.

```
<script>
var res_members = new Array();
var com_members = new Array();
</script>
<p><select name="member_id" id="member_id">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Alice (res)</option><script>res_members.push(1);</script>
    <option value="2">Bob (com)</option><script>com_members.push(2);</script>
    <option value="3">Carl (res)</option><script>res_members.push(3);</script>
</select></p>
<script>
    console.log(res_members, com_members);
    $(function(){
        $('#member_id').change(function(){
            alert($.inArray($('#member_id').val(), res_members));
            alert($.inArray($('#member_id').val(), com_members));
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you go with something simpler and more convenient like this:

```
<p><select name="member_id" id="member_id">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option class="res" value="1">Alice (res)</option>
    <option class="com" value="2">Bob (com)</option>
    <option class="res" value="3">Carl (res)</option>
</select></p>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#member_id').change(function(){
            var isRes = $(this).find(':selected').hasClass('res');
            alert(isRes ? "res" : "com");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/XWY4k/)**.

**Update: Why your current code doesn't work**

It's because you are pushing integers into the array (with `push`), while you are searching for strings with `$.inArray`. Changing either of these would make the existing code work.

So one solution would be to push in strings:

```
<option value="1">Alice (res)</option><script>res_members.push("1");</script>
<option value="2">Bob (com)</option><script>com_members.push("2");</script>
<option value="3">Carl (res)</option><script>res_members.push("3");</script>
```

And another would be to look for integers:

```
alert($.inArray(parseInt($(this).val()), res_members));
alert($.inArray(parseInt($(this).val()), com_members));
```

Evidently `$.inArray` compares haystack elements with the needle using operator `===`.

Comment: Obviously I need more coffee.